# IIS Log Analyzer

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

I want to analyze the IIS logs for a website for things like hits, keywords, countries accessed from etc.

Has anyone used any (free) tools that were useful from this regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [LogParser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659).  Blog article about how to use it [here](http://blog.trivadis.com/blogs/michaelkoenings/archive/2008/01/10/how-to-query-iis-logs-with-log-parser.aspx).  You need to be comfortable with SQL to use it, though.  There's a [GUI for it](http://en.serialcoder.net/logiciels/visual-logparser.aspx) apparently, too.  Don't have any experience with that, though.

Comment: there is a new GUI in town.. http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2012/03/07/introducing-log-parser-studio.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Nihuo web log analyzer](http://www.loganalyzer.net) is very simple, easy to configure and very good in analyzing iis and apache access log files. The reports generated by this tool are also very good.

You can use it freely with full function for 30 days evaluation period.

============================================

updated: The software is developed by myself.

Comment: It's not good when you promote own product without any disclosure.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score -4):

There is a simple answer to this don't..

Log files are next to useless to look at your website traffic, there are massively inaccurate, log file analysis is useful for network engineers looking at traffic management.

If you want to view who has looked at your website from where and with which broswer and what keyword was used to get there, just install goggle analytic although it does have a few downsides its much better for the information you require its also free.

Take a look at http://www.googlelytics.net/awstats-log-file-analysis-vs-google-analytics/ for a view of each.

Comment: Would not agree. Everything that does not fire javascript on the page, gets lost in google analytics. For example if you have a 404 but no 404 page, you will miss it.

Comment: Although Google analytic has its issues, as do all data miners these issues are much less than log files, which are completely useless for information regarding users, simply because they cant differentiate between them.

Comment: Google Analytics won't tell you 302s, 404s, resource not founds, and everything else that IIS logs are meant to do.    You need a successful page render to make a useful Analytic.   IIS logs give you *much* more than that.    What if a user isn't seeing something because of random 500s or the like?    GA won't help you one bit, there.

Comment: Your right Jason Google analytics wont tell you 302, 404, but Google webmaster will as so will New relic. Both of which are far better than log files. 

BUT the questions was hits, counties, keywords for that I stand by the fact that log files are next to useless.